# Are a convert's children considered to be of Jewish lineage?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, malchut-royalty, parashas-shoftim

Last week's parsha talks about appointing a Jewish king over Israel, and that it is prohibited to appoint a king who is not of Jewish lineage, even if he is a convert.

At what point are one's children considered to be of Jewish lineage (if both parents are converts)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rambam in [Hilchot Melachim 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1.4?lang=bi) writes:

> A convert may not be appointed king, even after many generations, until one has a Jewish mother.

[Kesef Mishneh (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1.4.1?lang=bi) writes that the same is true if he has a Jewish father.

So as soon as one parent is not a convert (nor descended solely from converts) the child is eligible to be appointed king.

Comment: IIRC aren't a lot of modern-day Jews descended from the Khazar converts? How far back do you need to trace things?

Comment: I believe that the notion that many Jews today descend from Khazars is a myth with roots in antisemitism, not genetics.